# add new item of RecyclerView from other fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have `buyfragment` that have List of items added on RecyclerView. I want from another fragment (`sellfragment`) to add new item by a button calles(`startselling`) ..So I just need a right code for `lstDressAdd()` method or for onClick (`startselling`)button

this is the (`buyfragment`):

```
 public class buyFragment extends Fragment {

public List<Dresses> lstDress;
 RecyclerView myrv;
RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter;


  @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
 @ Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false);


lstDress = new ArrayList<>();

//DRESSES DATA
lstDress.add(new Dresses("flora V-neck Drawstring A-line dress", "Bersheka", "new", 150.0, R.drawable.dress22));
lstDress.add(new Dresses("Button front flounce waist floral dress", "Pull&Bear", "new", 200.0, R.drawable.dress2));
lstDress.add(new Dresses("Shirred waist split hem Flower print dress", "Stradivarius", "new", 199.0, R.drawable.dress1));
lstDress.add(new Dresses("flora print square neck split hem midi dress", "MANGO", "new", 175.0, R.drawable.e));
lstDress.add(new Dresses("confetti heart surplice neck knot sleeve dress", "ZARA", "new", 168.0, R.drawable.dress22));
lstDress.add(new Dresses("flora V-neck Drawstring A-line dress", "ZARA", "new", 100.0, R.drawable.dress2));
lstDress.add(new Dresses("Shirred waist split hem Flower print dress", "Stradivuse", "new", 199.0, R.drawable.dress1));



myrv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviwe_id);
myAdapter = (new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstDress));
myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

return view;
 }


  public void lstDressAdd(String dress_title, String brand, String use, Double price) {

  lstDress.add(new Dresses(dress_title, brand, use, price, R.drawable.dress1));

}}
```

and this the (sellfragment):

```
     startselling=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button3) ;
     startselling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String text = brands.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String Use;
        if(newradio.getText().toString()=="New dress")
            Use="New";
        else
            Use="Used";
        String d=dress_title.getText().toString();

        Double p=Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
        if(d==null &&p==null&&Use==null&&text==null){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "you need to complete the dress Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
        buyFragment n=new buyFragment();
        n.lstDressAdd(dress_title.getText().toString(),text,Use,Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString()));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

    }
});
```

**pleses help me this is my college project and the due date after two days**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add a new item to the list and notify your recyclerView after that.
  `n.lstDressAdd(dress_title.getText().toString(),text,Use,Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString()));
n.myAdapter.notifyItemInserted()`

Comment: notifyItemInserted(int position),, how i know which position

Answer (score 0):

try to this code.

```
public void lstDressAdd(String dress_title, String brand, String use, Double price) {

      lstDress.add(new Dresses(dress_title, brand, use, price, R.drawable.dress1));
      myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
      myAdapter = (new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstDress)); 
}
```

**[Edit]**

Comment: adapter.lstDress not avalibale